# How to add a query string to a route when the page load?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC 3 web site, when my page first loads, the URL looks like this: http://mysite.com.
 However, I'd like it to look like this: http://mysite.com?user=123 (?user=123 is the important part).

How do I append a query string at the really begging in Asp.Net MVC 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this. but user becomes `302 Redirect`

```
public ActionResult Index(int? user)
{
    if (user == null)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { user = 123 });

    // do something...
}
```

Comment: do you know any way to keep a 200 status instead od 302?